# Query counting excluded category on paged loop

Tags: loop, query-posts, paged

I have an Index.php with a basic loop with this query before:

```
<?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array(
      'category_name' => 'work',
      'orderby' => 'asc',
      'paged' => $paged
    );
    query_posts($args); 
?>
```

Which works. But when I count the amount of pages using max_num_pages it says there are 5 pages worth of posts in the 'category_name' => 'work' but I know that there are not and whats happening is its including the other posts outside of this category.

How do I stop that from happening and get the loop to just display the actual amount of pages containing posts categorised with 'work' only?

Comment: Something like this? `function vs_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'category__not_in', array( 13 ) ); 
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'vs_pre_get_posts' );`

Answer (score 0):

`query_posts()` should not be used in general and especially when dealing with pagination.

You need to be making adjustments before template is reached, usually via [pre-get-posts](/questions/tagged/pre-get-posts) hook, on which there is plenty of material on site.